# echo "root" when using $USER

Tags: bash, sudo

I'd like to understand bash better and when variables are evaluated.

When using `sudo` the user environment that can be checked out using `env` is exchanged with the root environment. Hence `env` and `sudo env` yield different results.

Now if I am doing `sudo echo "I am $USER"!` the result is `I am my-username!`
instead of `I am root!`, presumably because the $USER variable is looked up before the sudo command is excuted.

How can I use that same command so that `I am root!` is printed? Do I need some switches or change the string somehow?

Comment: You need to switch user use `sudo su - root` or something equivalent. If you do sudo env you'll see the environment variables being set

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the command `sudo echo "$USER"`, `bash` evaluates `$USER` first and then executes the command. In that case your username is printed.

If you want to print the `root` username, the parameter expansion must be done as the root user. It can be done using `bash -c` command:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "$USER"'
```

Comment: Huh, I tried `sudo /bin/bash -c "echo I am $USER!"` and gave up there, but apparently both your solution AND `sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo I am $USER!'` work. I never thought to try if maybe double quotes do interpolation and single quotes don't [which is indeed the case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/6301103). Just didn't know what to look for. Thanks for the answer!